# Configure application on Google Cloud Platform with environment variables

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform

I'm a newbie with Google Cloud App Engine and I want to deploy my simple Node.js application. I need to configure it for "production" environment. For example, I want to provide some credentials for email box, which my application is going to query for new emails.
I like to use [nconf](https://github.com/indexzero/nconf) npm package, it gives me powerful and flexible configuration via command-line arguments or environment variables. I don't need to hard-code possibly secure values in source code.

Is there a way to configure environment variables or command-line arguments for an application in Google Developer Console?

P. S.
I found from [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_app_yaml_Defining_environment_variables), that one can inline environment variables in `app.yml` config file:

```
env_variables:
    FOO: 'myapp.bar'
```

But this is still not suitable for me, since `app.yml` is staged in git.

Comment: tag correctly. its not appengine

Comment: @ZigMandel, fixed, sorry for that.